# How to redirect crawlers requests to pre-rendered pages when using Amazon S3?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, seo, single-page-application

## Problem

I have a static SPA site built with Angular and hosted on Amazon S3. I'm trying to make my pre-rendered pages accessible by crawlers, but I can't redirect the crawlers requests since Amazon S3 does not offer a URL Rewrite option and the Redirect rules are limited.

## What I have

I've added the following meta-tag to the `<head>` of my **index.html** page:

```html
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Also, my SPA is using pretty URLs (without the hash `#` sign) with HTML5 push state.

With this setup, when a crawler finds my `http://mywebsite.com/about` link, it will make a `GET` request to `http://mywebsite.com/about?_escaped_fragment_=`. This is a [pattern defined by Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification?hl=en) and followed by others crawlers.

What I need is to answer this request with a pre-rendered version of the **about.html** file. I've already done this pre-rendering with Phantom.js, but I can't serve the correct file to crawlers because Amazon S3 do not have a rewrite rule.

In a **nginx** server, the solution would be to add a rewrite rule like:

```
location / {
  if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=") { 
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /snapshots/$1.html break; 
  } 
}
```

But in Amazon S3, I'm limited by their [redirect rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax) based on KeyPrefixes and HttpErrorCodes. The `?_escaped_fragment_=` is not  a KeyPrefix, since it appears at the end of the URL, and it gives no HTTP error since Angular will ignore it.

## What I've tried

I've started trying using dynamic templates with ngRoute, but later I've realized that I can't solve this with any Angular solution since I'm targeting crawlers that can't execute JavaScript.

With Amazon S3, I have to stick with their redirect rules.

I've managed to get it working with an ugly workaround. If I create a new rule for each page, I'm done:

```xml
<RoutingRules>

  <!-- each page needs it own rule -->
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>about?_escaped_fragment_=</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>mywebsite.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>snapshots/about.html</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>

</RoutingRules>
```

As you can see in this solution, each page will need its own rule. Since Amazon limits to only 50 redirect rules, this is not a viable solution.

Another solution would be to forget about pretty URLs and use hashbangs. With this, my link would be `http://mywebsite.com/#!about` and crawlers would request this with `http://mywebsite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=about`. Since the URL will start with `?_escaped_fragment_=`, it can be captured with the KeyPrefix and just one redirect rule would be enough. However, I don't want to use ugly URLs.

**So, how can I have a static SPA in Amazon S3 and be SEO-friendly?**

Comment: I've realized how to solve this just after I've finished writing my question. Since I've spent many hours trying to figure out this through a wrong path, I've posted my answer below in hope to help others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short Answer

Amazon S3 (and Amazon CloudFront) does not offer rewrite rules and have only limited redirect options. However, you **don't** need to redirect or rewrite your URL requests. Just pre-render **all** HTML files and **upload them following your website paths**.

Since a user browsing the webpage has JavaScript enabled, Angular will be triggered and will take control over the page which results into a re-rendering of the template. With this, all Angular functionalities will be available for this user.

Regarding the crawler, the pre-rendered page will be enough.

## Example

If you have a website named **www.myblog.com** and a link to another page with the URL **www.myblog.com/posts/my-first-post**. Probably, your Angular app has the following structure: an **index.html** file that is in your root directory and is responsible for everything. The page **my-first-post** is a partial HTML file located in **/partials/my-first-post.html**.

The solution in this case is to use a pre-rendering tool at deploy time. You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) for this, but you can't use a middleware tool like [Prerender](http://prerender.io) because you have a static site hosted in Amazon S3.

You need to use this pre-render tool to create two files: **index.html** and **my-first-post**. Note that **my-first-post** will be an HTML file without the **.html** extension, but you will need to set its Content-Type to **text/html** when you upload to Amazon S3.

You will place the **index.html** file in your root directory and **my-first-post** inside a folder named **posts** to match your URL path **/posts/my-first-post**.

With this approach, the crawler will be able to retrieve your HTML file and the user will be happy to use all Angular functionalities.

**Note:** this solution requires that all files be referenced using the root path. Relative paths will not work if you visit the link **www.myblog.com/posts/my-first-post**.

By root path, I mean:

```html
<script src="/js/myfile.js"></script>
```

The wrong way, using relative paths, would be:

```html
<script src="js/myfile.js"></script>
```

## EDIT:

Below follows a small JavaScript code that I've used to prerender pages using PhantomJS. After installing PhantomJS and testing the script with a single page, add to your build process a script to prerender all pages before deploying your site.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

// since this tool will run before your production deploy, 
// your target URL will be your dev/staging environment (localhost, in this example)
var path = 'pages/my-page';
var url = 'http://localhost/' + path;

page.open(url, function (status) {

  if (status != 'success')
    throw 'Error trying to prerender ' + url;

  var content = page.content;
  fs.write(path, content, 'w');

  console.log("The file was saved.");
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Note: it looks like Node.js, but it isn't. It must be executed with Phantom executable and not Node.

Comment: It would be awesome if there was a script to run that could help with the pre-rendering.

Comment: @jjbskir, I've added the script that I've used to prerender one page.

Comment: Thats very cool! I could see that working for some of my projects, but not others. My projects that just have static html and I don't have much interactivity to them that would work, but then my projects that I am dynamically adding in views and controllers I would have issues. This weekend I started working on a way to pre render all of my angular pages - https://github.com/jjbskir/angular-prerender - would something like this help you also?

Comment: 2020 aproach? PhantomJS is deprecated, ANgular Universal exists... help please